# Cannot bind my Converter class in my XAML command that pass parameter

Tags: xaml, mvvm

This is my `XAML` that is trying to have my `ListView` pass a parameter to the `ViewModel` command.

```
xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"


<ListBox x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ParamConverter }"
                                    EventArgsConverterParameter ="{Binding Name}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And this is my converter:

```
public class ParamConverter : IEventArgsConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {
        var args = (SelectionChangedEventArgs)value;

        var name = parameter as string;

        return (string)name.ToString();
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> The resource "ParamConverter" could not be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your converter is not declared in XAML, you should add something like

```
<ListBox.Resources>
  <yournamespace:ParamConverter x:Key="ParamConverter"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

inside your listbox tags.

EDIT: I'm not an expert at all, so bear with my "imprecise" terms if any. I think you're missing something: there is no magic that allows your XAML to be aware of your C#. You need to tell XAML that somewhere in your code (in *yournamespace*) there will be a *ParamConverter* object, that can be referenced inside xaml with *ParamConverter* key.
You can declare your resource locally inside ListBox tags as suggested, or at outer scope if needed.
Once resource is declared inside XAML, you can access it via *StaticResource*.